# Java 8 and ignoring --release in compiler

Tags: java, java-8, java-9

I have a project that has to be dual compiled to java 8 and java 9.
And it fails because in case of java 9 we are using `--release` flag.
Is it possible for `javac` to ignore unknown flags (and not exit with error)?

Comment: Why not just use JDK9 to compile both versions using `--release`? It's not always possible for every codebase, but it's ostensibly what that flag is for.

Comment: Good point, I'll need to check that my jenkins and the plugin that runs after the build won't be affected by it.

Comment: @millimoose I agree. JDK 8 is not necessary at all.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov - I wouldn't say "at all" - I've bravely ran away from a huge legacy codebase that was JDK6 based in the year of our lord 2017 that wouldn't compile under `--release 6` because it was using some XML related classes that were available in JDK6 but aren't part of the bootclasspath for that release in JDK6. And had a bunch of other issues with the CXF stub generator not working properly when Maven invoked it with Java 6. (Which lead me to investigate the Maven "toolchains" feature and realize it won't help me at all because a plugin has to be toolchain-aware and those weren't etc...)

Comment: *Anyhow* there are very plausible cases where sticking to the older JDK entirely is the most straightforward way to doing the thing you're being paid for. But `--release` should be the go-to method especially for reasonably new or maintained codebases.

Comment: OK, but using release doesn't solve a problem if I use a Jenkins plugin, that requries Jdk8 (in my case Blackduck scan).